# How does one avoid "invalid memory address or null pointer dereference" errors?

Tags: go

I'm wondering how I can structure this example code to help avoid null pointer dereference panics:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Astruct struct {
    Number int
    Letter string
}

type Bstruct struct {
    foo int
    AStructList *[]Astruct
}

type Cstruct struct {
    Bstruct
}

func (a *Astruct) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Number = %d, Letter = %s", a.Number, a.Letter)
}

func main() {
    astructlist := make([]Astruct, 3)      // line 1
    for i := range astructlist {           // line 2
        astructlist[i] = Astruct{i, "a"}   // line 3
    }                                      // line 4
    c := new(Cstruct)
    c.Bstruct = Bstruct{100, &astructlist} // line 6

    for _, x := range(*c.Bstruct.AStructList) {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", &x)
    }
}
```

If I omit lines 1-4 and 6 of main(), I get a null pointer dereference panic. Short of checking if c != nil, is there a way to avoid these panics?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: your problem is not that `c` is a nil pointer, but that `c.Bstruct.AStructList` is a nil pointer

Comment: Yes indeed. I understand where the error was coming from, but what I wanted to know (and probably didn't make clear in the original question) was "is there a better/more idiomatic way to avoid this problem?" I spent some time looking at the code and figure there must be a better way to structure the structs as to avoid hitting nil pointer problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, you could use idiomatic Go. Change `AStructList *[]Astruct` to `AStructList []*Astruct`. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Astruct struct {
    Number int
    Letter string
}

type Bstruct struct {
    foo         int
    AStructList []*Astruct
}

type Cstruct struct {
    Bstruct
}

func (a *Astruct) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Number = %d, Letter = %s", a.Number, a.Letter)
}

func main() {
    astructlist := make([]*Astruct, 3)            // line 1
    for i := range astructlist {                  // line 2
        astructlist[i] = &Astruct{i, "a"}         // line 3 
    }                                             // line 4
    c := new(Cstruct)
    c.Bstruct = Bstruct{100, astructlist}         // line 6

    for _, x := range c.Bstruct.AStructList {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", x)
    }
}
```

In general, it's your responsibility to either assign a non-`nil` value to a pointer or test for `nil` before its use. When you allocate memory without explicitly intializing it, it's set to the zero value for the type, which is `nil` for pointers.

> [The zero value](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#The_zero_value)
>
> When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a
>   declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization
>   is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each
>   element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false
>   for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil
>   for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps. This
>   initialization is done recursively, so for instance each element of an
>   array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value is specified.

Comment: Hi peterSO, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize that I could define Bstruct.AStructList as a slice of pointers rather than a pointer to a slice of Astructs. Cheers!